# How to selectively open lines in a txt file

Tags: python, if-statement, txt

I have a txt file called song.txt and want to print out all the lines in the file which contain a certain word. I have tried using an if statement and am getting no output. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

```
**with open('song.txt', 'r') as s:
      if 'still' in s.readlines():
            print(s.readlines())**
```

FYI: I am an absolute amateur .

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('song.txt', 'r') as s:
    for line in s.readlines():
        if 'still' in line:
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('song.txt', 'r') as s: 
    for line in s: # saves memory by not loading entire file.
        if 'still' in line:
            print(line)
```